# What does "Ces choses-là" mean?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire

Why is there "là"?

Can't it be written as "ces choses"?

Comment: It can be written as *ces choses.* You usually only add *là* if you want to distinguish *ces choses-là* (*those things*) from *ces choses-ci* (*these things*) or if you want to give *ces choses* some extra emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

*-ci* and *-là* roughly translates as *this/those here* and *this/those there*
*Ces choses-là*= those things (over) there.

Comment: In English, we would usually say *this/these here* and *that/those there*. And since *this* already contains the idea of *here* in it, we generally just say *this thing* and only say *this thing here* when we want to give it extra emphasis.